# Mapping hourly image collection over feature collection with daily aggregation of image stats

Tags: google-earth-engine, mapping, feature-collection, imagecollection

I have a feature collection ~ 1600 polygons across the U.S. I have an image collection (NLDAS) where each image is hourly data for the summertime (92 days) across 3 decades ~ 24 hours x 92 days x 30 years = 66,240 images.

I am interested in getting a daily max heat index (HI) for each feature for every day in the time period (92 days x 30 years). NLDAS does not have a HI band directly, it must be computed hourly as a new band. Then get max for the day.

I previously used the method of mapping over an image collection w/ reduce regions (returns: hourly data for the feature collection). Then I export this result and do the daily max HI computation outside of GEE because I didn't see a clear way to do a daily aggregation of hourly images within reduce regions. Exporting worked... but it takes 1 - 2 days for a few hundred polygons from the feature collection because it's a massive amount of data. That code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/253e7721f39d197154e882fe3cc2da69).

In an effort to save computation and export time/space, I am instead trying to compute daily max HI for each feature but am struggling with the correct code structure. **In the code at [this link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7d9384e40ecfd2c7e7d32faeeae177d9)**, I attempt to add daily max HI as a property to the feature, for each time step of the image collection. But i get an error. Does anyone have a good solution to this? My goal is something like the following (or rows and columns inverted) where the numbers are the daily max HI:

| Feature | June, 01, 1990 | June, 02, 1990 | ... | Aug, 31, 2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Feature_1 | 90 | 95 | 82 | 103 |
| Feature_2 | 87 | 98 | 89 | 90 |
| ... | 92 | 98 | 89 | 90 |
| Feature_n | 92 | 91 | 90 | 98 |